# string to Numeric/Date in PostgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql

1. I have a string with a `numeric`/`date` value in it. I need to convert the string to apply `NumericGetDatum()`/`DateADTGetDatum` function respectively. How do I go about it?

   I looked into to_char() function, but, I wouldn't know the format to convert to (how many digits/date format).
2. When I query `information_schema.columns` table to know about the datatype of a certain column, I get the value as `numeric`. PostgreSQL mentions in the table http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE, the different `numeric` types available. Why doesn't the query return one of those types, instead of `numeric`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Most types have their own file in `src/backend/utils/adt/` containing a variety of supporting functions. The string conversion routine for `numeric`, in `src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c`, is called `numeric_in()` (likewise for `date`). Search the Postgres codebase for examples of how these functions are called.
2. There are many different types for representing numbers (i.e. "numeric types"). One of these types is actually called `numeric` (it appears in the table you linked to).

Comment: As a side-note, if you're playing around with server-side C code, I'd forget about `information_schema` and get acquainted with `pg_catalog`

Comment: I was able to find the numeric_in usage, but not the date_in() usage in PostgreSQL. Could you give me any example usage for string to date conversion using date_in?

Comment: Judging by the `PG_GETARG_` calls in `date_in`, it's expecting one argument of type `cstring`. So the function call should be something like `DirectFunctionCall1(date_in, CStringGetDatum(...))`.